# Add info from one list to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have this two list, one with cities and one with lists of other infos. I would like to insert the name of the cities in index 0 of each list of the second list. Problem is at the end I have only one city name that is printed (the last one). Can somebody help me out with this ? Thank you !

```py
cities = ["Paris", "London", "New York"]

data = [
    ["", "", "", "", 1, 1, "Buildings"],
    ["", "", "", "", 2, 1, "Streets"],
    ["", "", "", "", 3, 1, "Avenues"],
    ["", "", "", "", 1, 2, "Buildings"],
    ["", "", "", "", 2, 2, "Streets"],
    ["", "", "", "", 3, 2, "Avenues"],
]

result = []
counter = -1
while counter != len(cities) - 1:
    counter += 1
    number = -1
    while number != len(data) - 1:
        number += 1
        data[number][0] = cities[counter]
        result.append(data[number])

print(result)
```

gives me

```py
result = [['New York', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues'], 
# (and so on)
]
```

while I'd rather have

```py
result = [['New York', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings'], 
['Paris', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets'], 
['Paris', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues'], 
['Paris', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings'], 
['Paris', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets'], 
['Paris', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues'], 
['Paris', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings'], 
['London', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets'], 
['London', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues'], 
['London', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings'], 
['London', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets'], 
['London', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues'], 
['London', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets'], 
['New York', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues']
]
```

Thank you

Comment: Right, because there is only one list called `data`.  You are appending rows from it into your `result` list, but if you change one copy, you change them all.  I'll propose a better way to do this below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that can help with your problem:

```
cities = ["Paris", "London", "New York"]

data = [
    ["", "", "", "", 1, 1, "Buildings"],
    ["", "", "", "", 2, 1, "Streets"],
    ["", "", "", "", 3, 1, "Avenues"],
    ["", "", "", "", 1, 2, "Buildings"],
    ["", "", "", "", 2, 2, "Streets"],
    ["", "", "", "", 3, 2, "Avenues"],
]

result = []
for i in cities:
  for j in data:
    result.append(j.copy()) #adding a copy of the list to result
    result[len(result) - 1][0] = i #editing the list we just added (the now last element in result) so the first element is the city

#printing the result
for i in result:
  print(i)
```

Output:

```
['Paris', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings']
['Paris', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets']
['Paris', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues']
['Paris', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings']
['Paris', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets']
['Paris', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues']
['London', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings']
['London', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets']
['London', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues']
['London', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings']
['London', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets']
['London', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues']
['New York', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings']
['New York', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets']
['New York', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues']
['New York', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings']
['New York', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets']
['New York', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues']
```

The way this code works is that:

For every city in the list `cities`, we first add a copy of every list inside of `data` to `result` and then change the value of the first element to the city.

I hope this helped! Let me know if you need any further help or clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to start from a template.  Python makes that hard, because you end up with references rather than copies.  Instead, build it out like this:

```
from pprint import pprint

cities = ["Paris", "London", "New York"]
layers = ['Buildings','Streets','Avenues']
data = []
for city in cities:
    for i in (1,2):
        for j,layer in enumerate(layers)
            data.append( [city, '', '', '', j+1, i, layer] )
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[['Paris', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings'],
 ['Paris', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets'],
 ['Paris', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues'],
 ['Paris', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings'],
 ['Paris', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets'],
 ['Paris', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues'],
 ['London', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings'],
 ['London', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets'],
 ['London', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues'],
 ['London', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings'],
 ['London', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets'],
 ['London', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues'],
 ['New York', '', '', '', 1, 1, 'Buildings'],
 ['New York', '', '', '', 2, 1, 'Streets'],
 ['New York', '', '', '', 3, 1, 'Avenues'],
 ['New York', '', '', '', 1, 2, 'Buildings'],
 ['New York', '', '', '', 2, 2, 'Streets'],
 ['New York', '', '', '', 3, 2, 'Avenues']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a one liner using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
result = [[city] + el[1:] for el in data for city in cities]
```

This is basically a double for loop, where we iterate over the cities in the first one (`for city in cities`) and then for each iteration, we iterate over the elements of data (`for el in data`). Then for each iteration, we concatenate the city in a list (`[city]` with the element of data with the entry at index 0 removed (`el[:1]`). In Python, list concatenation can be done using `+`.

I suggest you to learn the "Pythonic" way of manipulating lists, it will  make your code shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: Close, but make it `[city] + el[1:]` so you aren't adding an extra element per list.  :)

Comment: That's true, missed that part in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is your answer

```
result_1 = []
result_2 = []
for cities_index, cities in enumerate(cities):
    for line_data in data:
        print(cities)
        line_1 = line_data.copy()
        line_1[0] = cities
        print(line_1)
        result_1.append(line_1)
    result_2.extend(result_1)
print(result_2)
```